# How to store user all the information in Django sessions

Tags: django

i configured settings.py in database storing sessions and it is working properly but I am getting confuse how to collect and retrieve data in session

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

```
The configuration is set up in the INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE sections of the project (settings.py)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    ....

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ....



# Get a session value by its key (e.g. 'my_val'), raising a KeyError if the key is not present
my_val = request.session['my_val']

# Get a session value, setting a default if it is not present ('mini')
my_val = request.session.get('my_val', 'value')

# Set a session value
request.session['my_val'] = 'value'

# Delete a session value
del request.session['my_val']
```